# how can i validate span tag text using single xpath?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

My HTML code is below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-7">
<h1 class="h1_home">
<span>Welcome to the</span>
<br/>
<span>Automation Software Testing</span>
</h1>
<p class="col-xs-9 col-lg-12">
</div>
</div>
```

1. verify the page header text i use bellow code :

   ```
   String expected_txt = "Welcome to the Automation Software Testing";
   WebElement header_txt_elm=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//h1[@class='h1_home']//span"));
   String actual_headertxt = header_txt_elm.getText().toString();
   Assert.assertEquals( actual_headertxt.toLowerCase(), expected_txt.toLowerCase());
   ```
2. getting error:

   ```
   java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Welcome to the Automation Software Testing] but found [welcome to the]
   ```

Comment: FYI... you don't need the `.toString()` on `actual_headertxt`. `.getText()` already returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
String expected_txt = "Welcome to the Automation Software Testing";
WebElement header_txt_elm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Welcome to the']"));
WebElement header_txt_elm2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Automation Software Testing']"));
String actual_txt1=header_txt_elm.getText();
String actual_txt2=header_txt_elm2.getText();
String actual_txt=actual_txt1+actual_txt2;
Assert.assertEquals(actual_headertxt, expected_txt);
```

Comment: Example is not just enough!! It would be nice if valid explanation is given!! Thanks!!

Comment: I am getting the 2 text values from the web elements. Than i save the string values and i am concatenating the strings into a single string. then i compare the  values with the actual text.

Answer (score 1):

```
String expected_value = "Welcome to the Automation Software Testing";
WebElement header_value_elm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Welcome to the']"));
WebElement header_value_elm2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Automation Software Testing']"));
String actual_txt1=header_txt_elm.getText();
String actual_txt2=header_txt_elm2.getText();
String actual_txt=actual_txt1+actual_txt2;`enter code here`
Assert.assertEquals(actual_headertxt, expected_txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findElements()` instead and concatenate the results into one string before validating.  You'll probably want to normalize spaces (i.e. trim leading/trailing whitespace, convert newlines to blanks and multiple whitespaces to single spaces) and do the comparison case-insensitive as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just pull all the text from the `<h1>`.

```
String expected_txt = "Welcome to the Automation Software Testing";
WebElement header_txt_elm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='h1_home']"));
// WebElement header_txt_elm = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1.h1_home")); // CSS selector version

String actual_headertxt = header_txt_elm.getText();
Assert.assertEquals(actual_headertxt.toLowerCase(), expected_txt.toLowerCase());
```